# Passage Ranking using TFR-BERT: ValueError when importing libraries

Tags: tensorflow, bert-language-model

I'm trying to run the tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/ranking/tutorials/tfr_bert but I have trouble to set up the environment locally.

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_ranking as tfr
from official.nlp.configs import encoders
from tensorflow_ranking.extension.premade import tfrbert_task
```

Line 4 in the code above causes the following error:

ValueError: mutable default <class 'official.nlp.configs.encoders.AlbertEncoderConfig'> for field albert is not allowed: use default_factory

Does anyone have any clue of what is the problem here ? Is it a conflict between libraries ?

Thanks!